# Best practice to config the dynamically generated file

Tags: python, django

I made the file like this in views.py.

```
csvDir = 'exportedCsv/'
file_path = csvDir + 'test.csv'
df.to_csv(path_or_buf=file_path,sep=',',float_format='%.2f',index=False,decimal=",",encoding='utf_8_sig')
```

Dynamically generate file and path the filepath to html.

Now there is my file in /exportedCsv/test.csv

However I have no way to access this from html.

My idea is basiclly wrong???

What should I do when I want to make csv file and let the user download it??

Comment: If you really want to write it to the filesystem you have to write it under your MEDIA_ROOT (just make sure it has a unique name). Note that you can also write a csv directly to the response object (with the correct content type and headers) - there is an example in the doc.

Comment: Thanks for your commen.  I will use MEDIA_ROOT instead. I googled around and found that it has MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL it helps me well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a link to it in your html like so: `<a href="exportedCsv/test.csv"> Download </a>`